# Text align with special character in tabularx

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I have a table with two rows and three columns. One of the rows value is `A#B`, I escape the special character `#` with `\`, but the value is *not* wrapped properly and crosses the column.

Comment: is not wrapped *

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please prepare a complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.

Comment: You can try to use ```\#```